# Displaying one row with one timestamp and a corresponding x-integer array as x rows with x timestamps and one corresponding integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

Apologies for the poorly worded question, I don't know how to succinctly describe my problem. I am working with data from a sensor that scans a room every 10 minutes to see how many people are in it. The data looks  something like this

```
reading_id |      timestamp      |    values      |          
--------------------------------------------------
1          | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 | {1,1,6,17,4,4} |
2          | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 | {3,4,6,3,0,8}  |
3          | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 | {0,0,0,0,0,0}  |
```

Is there any way I can have it look like this?

```
reading_id |      timestamp      |    values      |
-------------------------------------------------- 
1          | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 | 1              |
1          | 2019-02-28 01:10:00 | 1              |
1          | 2019-02-28 01:20:00 | 6              |
1          | 2019-02-28 01:30:00 | 17             |
1          | 2019-02-28 01:40:00 | 4              |
1          | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 | 4              |
2          | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 | 3              |
...
```

I'm not sure what would happen to the reading_id but I do not need it regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unnest with ordinality to get the index of each array element and use that to add the 10 minute intervals.

```
select t.reading_id,
       t."timestamp" + interval '10 minutes' * (u.idx - 1) AS timestamp,
       u.value
from the_table t
   cross join unnest(t."values") with ordinality AS u(value, idx)
order by 1,2;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/TEB87353

Comment: Sweet, didn't know about ordinality!

Comment: Ended up using @fphilipe answer but this works great as well, thanks!

Comment: @hov . . . This answer is correct.  fphilipe's answer does not guarantee that the results will be in the correct time sequence.  I would recommend that you use this method *and* that you accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to unnest the data:

```
SELECT
    reading_id,
    timestamp,
    unnest(values) AS value
FROM table;
```

This gives us:

```
 reading_id |      timestamp      | value
------------+---------------------+-------
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 |     1
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 |     1
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 |     6
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 |    17
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 |     4
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 |     4
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 |     3
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 |     4
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 |     6
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 |     3
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 |     0
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 |     8
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 |     0
(18 rows)
```

Then, for each partition of `reading_id` you want to add 10 minutes for each row. This can be done as follows:

```
SELECT
    reading_id,
    timestamp + ((row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY reading_id)) - 1) * '10 minutes'::interval AS timestamp,
    value
FROM (
    SELECT
        reading_id,
        timestamp,
        unnest(values) AS value
    FROM table
) AS data;
```

Note that `row_number()` starts at 1. Thus, we have to subtract 1 before multiplying it with 10 minutes.

This yields what you're after:

```
 reading_id |      timestamp      | value
------------+---------------------+-------
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:00:00 |     1
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:10:00 |     1
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:20:00 |     6
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:30:00 |    17
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:40:00 |     4
          1 | 2019-02-28 01:50:00 |     4
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:00:00 |     3
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:10:00 |     4
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:20:00 |     6
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:30:00 |     3
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:40:00 |     0
          2 | 2019-02-28 02:50:00 |     8
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:00:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:10:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:20:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:30:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:40:00 |     0
          3 | 2019-02-28 03:50:00 |     0
(18 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add tabled function to split string like this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        token       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

then you can just run this select:

```
select [reading_id],
DATEADD(MINUTE, 10 * (ItemNumber - 1), [timestamp]) as [timestamp],
[token] as [values]
from 
Table1
outer apply ((SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] (
   SUBSTRING([values],2, LEN([values])-2)
  ,','))) split
```

Comment: This is not valid for Postgres

Comment: sorry  I didn't notice